# How can I delete an item in a List ? SwiftUI

Tags: list, swiftui

I'm trying to edit a List (composed of mutable strings) with an edit button and a function. My code is:

```
struct annotationsView: View {
    
    
    @State private var text = ""
    //    annotations
    @State var annotations : [[AnnData]] = [[]]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Form{
                HStack{
                    TextField("Add your annotations here", text: $text)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    
                    Button("Submit") {
                        annotations[annotations.count - 1].append(AnnData(Anntext: text))
                        self.hideKeyboard()
                        text = ""
                    }
                }
                List{
                    ForEach(annotations.indices, id:\.self){index in
                        
                        ForEach(annotations[index].indices, id:\.self){annotationIndex in
                            
                            Text(annotations[index][annotationIndex].Anntext)
                        }.onDelete(perform: self.deleteItem) //<-- Here
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
        .background(
            Image("Background")
                .resizable()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Annotations"), displayMode: .inline)
        )
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
    }
    
    private func deleteItem(at indexSet: IndexSet) {
        annotations.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
    }
}
struct AnnData : Identifiable{
    
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var Anntext: String
}
```

Currently, I can not delete a single item; when I delete one, the rest are deleted automatilcally. Also, after that I can't add some items inside the List.
Would you mind explaining what's wrong here?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete item within a loop because your data is a two-dimensional array.
Like this

```
List{
    ForEach(annotations.indices, id:\.self){index in
        
        ForEach(annotations[index].indices, id:\.self){annotationIndex in
            
            Text(annotations[index][annotationIndex].Anntext)
        }
        .onDelete { (indexSet) in
            annotations[index].remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
        }//<-- Here
    }
}
```